# Switch to split window on the same line

Tags: vim

I have two buffers open in vim using a vertical split which are linked using :set scrollbind.

Is there a way to switch between the windows so that the cursor remains on the same (relative) row when I do switch between them using the ctrl+w commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mapping will do what you need

Do this in the left window:

```
:nmap <right> :let linenum=getpos('.')[1]\|:wincmd l\|:call cursor(linenum,0)<cr>
```

and do this in the right window:

```
:nmap <left> :let linenum=getpos('.')[1]\|:wincmd h\|:call cursor(linenum,0)<cr>
```

Then you can use the left and right arrows to switch between the windows and the cursor will go to the same line in the other window.

Edit:

I didn't read your question carefully (shame on me!:).

Here's how to get exactly what you wanted:

On the left window:

```
:nnoremap <right> :let offset=winline()\|wincmd l\|exe 'normal ' . offset . 'H'<cr>
```

and on the right:

```
:nnoremap <left> :let offset=winline()\|wincmd h\|exe 'normal ' . offset . 'H'<cr>
```

Have fun!

Comment: I bow to your superior vim-foo.  Do you know of a way to do the same that uses relative positioning of the cursor from the top of the screen?

Comment: Quoting @ZyX: "don't use *map unless you know why you prefer it to nore version"

Answer (score 3):

Vim version 7.3 added a `cursorbind` option:

> When this option is set, as the cursor in the current
>       window moves other cursorbound windows (windows that also have
>       this option set) move their cursors to the corresponding line and
>       column.  This option is useful for viewing the
>       differences between two versions of a file (see 'diff'); in diff mode,
>       inserted and deleted lines (though not characters within a line) are
>       taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

`^W+r` (switch buffers) followed by `^W^W` (return cursor back)

Comment: That just moves the buffers around really, what I really want to do is something where `^W+h` moves me to the right-side window without changing the row of the cursor.  The default behavior of vim is to return to the same row the cursor was on when I was last in that buffer, which I would like to override.  I hope that makes sense, it seems difficult to explain.